# What is the VK_KEY / scancode for this key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keycode, virtual-keyboard, scancodes

I am using GetASyncKeyState (C++) to check for keys.
I don't know what the name of this key is:
[image]

How is this key named? What is the VK_ or Scancode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   VK_LMENU : Left menu key (0xA4)
   VK_RMENU : Right menu key (0xA5)
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has many more interesting keys I didn't even know that exist, such as "right windows key" o.O

Apparently, this key is reported by `VK_APPS`

Comment: ah right, eneed to wait 8 minutes before accepting. :o However I thought VK_*MENU is (L/R)ALT O_O [this](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html) source is confusing me

Comment: Use Spy++ on a new opened notepad to figure out any key you want to know about by just pressing it.

Answer (score 0):

VK_APPS is an extended key and its scan code is D5E0 (D5E1 on some systems). More on Windows key maps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx).